# How to setup a download folder in Apache HTTPD?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I want to setup a download folder on HTTPD so that the folder it self is indexed and the files are downloaded when clicked.

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
# Downloads
<Directory /var/www/html/downloads>
  Allow from all
  Options Indexes
  <Files "?*">
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

Browsing to /downloads gives me the index of the folder. But clicking the files doesn't open download prompt.

Any ideas?
Regards,

--
Edit:

There seems to be something about my browser. Indeed it **IS** working.

Comment: Which version of apache do you use?

Comment: what does it mean didn't work? Which error do you get in the server, what does the error.log say about it? and how is your request like? mod_autoindex and Options Indexes is all you need, so that vague "didn't work" is an aweful way to describe your issue.

Comment: Apache/2.2.15.

The contents of /downloads are index but clicking on then open then on browser instead of asking for download.

I think that was something about caching in my browser. I left the computer here tomorrow night and came back today. Now it IS working. The content of the configuration file is the same.

By the way, I'm on a Centos 6.5 machine.

Thank you guys!